# Syntax error in nohup (...)

Tags: bash, shell, nohup, subshell

I am trying to test the `nohup` command in the bash shell by executing a command in the background and logging out and back in again and expecting the output of the command to be in the `nohup.out` file.
Here is the command I am trying to execute:

```
$ nohup (sleep 120; echo "job done") &
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `sleep`
```

Comment: Remove the subshell

Answer (score 17):

[The `nohup` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html) is not [a keyword](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Compound-Commands); it can't be given a subshell as the command to run, and instead it requires an actual runnable command:

```
nohup bash -c 'sleep 120; echo "job done"' &
```

Bash is giving you a syntax error because it thinks you're trying to declare a function called "nohup", which is the only case where a bare parenthesis can appear in the second word on the command line:

```
nohup () { ... ; }
```

The error message is telling you (obscurely) that it expected to see the right parenthesis there and not the word "sleep".